# Is it a bad idea to use `throw`-`catch` for normal cases rather than exceptional cases?

Tags: ruby, exception, throw

My understanding is that `throw` is typically used to capture the exceptional cases as in the following:

```
def some_callee_method
  ...
  if something_went_wrong then throw(:foo, "something wrong")
  else normal_return_value
  end
end
def some_caller_method
  e = catch(:foo) do
    ...
    some_callee_method
    ...
  end
  raise some_processed_error if e == "something wrong"
  ... # Unthrown. Continue normal cases
end
```

But in the usage above, the return value from a `throw` and and the normal return value from `some_callee_method` are mixed up when they are received as the return value of the `catch` block (`e` above), and so there needs to be a conditioning after the `catch` block to separate that.

I felt this cumbersome, and for certain cases when possible, I though of reversing it: `throw` in the normal cases rather than the exceptional cases as in the following. (In this case, something can go wrong only in the last step of `some_callee_method` or it can continue to the end of `some_callee_method` even when something went wrong.)

```
def some_callee_method
  ...
  throw(:foo, normal_return_value) unless something_went_wrong
end
def some_caller_method
  e = catch(:foo) do
    ...
    some_callee_method
    raise some_processed_error
  end
  ... # Thrown. Continue normal cases
end
```

My concern is the efficiency of using `throw`-`catch`. In the first case, `throw` was used to signal an exceptional case, which only happens at most once per program execution, and is a case that a user should put effort to avoid, so performance is not a big issue. However, in the second case, lots of `throw`-`catch` will be happening in the normal case. Performance-wise, is it a bad idea to adopt the second form?

---

Or, more generally, does frequent use of `throw`-`catch` have a negative impact on performance?

It is sometimes said that using `rescue` to catch an exception in the normal cases should be avoided because of its negative impact on performance. For example, to check if a string represents an integer, the second form below is preferred over the first form (I suppose not only because of its elegance).

```
def is_int?(string)
  Integer(string)
  true
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end

def is_int?(string)
  not string.empty? and string !~ /\D/
end
```

I was wondering whether it is the same for `throw`-`catch`.

Comment: `throw-catch` looks like some elegant form of dreaded `goto` statements. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

I don't believe throw/catch is generally an appropriate flow-control mechanism between methods, although you *can* use it that way if you try hard enough. The real use case for throw/catch is for handling nested loops. See longer explanation below.

### Catch/Throw is for Nested Loops

The primary use case for throw and catch is for exiting deeply nested flow-control structures. From [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/):

> While the exception mechanism of raise and rescue is great for abandoning execution when things go wrong, it's sometimes nice to be able to jump out of some deeply nested construct during normal processing. This is where catch and throw come in handy.

While they give some examples in the book, you might consider a more complex case like:

```
catch :done do
  while true do
    while true do
      while true do
        while true do
          nested_levels = 4
          puts "levels: #{nested_levels}"
          throw :done, nested_levels
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
#=> 4
```

If you just replace `throw` with a single `break` you'll still keep looping forever. Now consider how many `break` keywords and conditions you would need to break out of all the containing loops explicitly. The throw/catch combination lets you unwind out of arbitrarily-deep loops, and can be extremely handy for situations where you don't want to `return` from a method or raise an exception just to exit this set of loops.

Comment: Or: don't ever have deeply nested constructs, and avoid `throw...catch` altogether. I've never seen a case where I was convinced that this sort of nesting was better than the alternatives.

Comment: One good example can be found [here](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/07/12/throw-catch-raise-rescue--im-so-confused/)

Answer (score 0):

`throw/catch` makes sense when the goal is to navigate through some collection until an object is found, and immediately return it. The intermediate states are not of interest: the only thing that really matters is the object of the search.

Ten buddies go to a football game. One of them has all the tickets. They line up outside the stadium entrance. The ticket taker asks the first one in line to produce a ticket, but he doesn't have one.

He asks the next guy in line. He doesn't have the tickets either. Each guy asks the next guy in line for the tickets. Eventually, the tickets are found.

Now at this point, many programmers would insist that the guy with the tickets should give them to the guy in front of him, who would give them to the guy in front of *him*, etc., until they get to the guy at the front of the line. But instead, the guy holding the tickets can just cry out "I have the tickets!" and give them to the ticket taker. That's how `throw/catch` works.